# Why not be known for more than 13 photos

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm sorry if I type can not properly EnglishExplain the problem

1. 14 png image format with different names, placed in drawable
2. And images using the image view in my activity
3. But when run in virtual machines, error and will not run.
4. But when 13 to put the image with different names , properly run, and all images are displayed

I wanted to see where is the problem
If I wanted to put together the picture of the problem.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Naming convention of file.there must be an issue with file name. do one thing change image name and after that set any image to image view and run application.

Comment: Thanks jimmy
But the problem is not resolved.    Name photos like this
image_1
image_2
.
.
image_14

Comment: I think the problem is the volume of low memory![pic1](https://i.imgsafe.org/7e0842c.jpg).![pic2](https://i.imgsafe.org/80dffc1.jpg).![pic3](https://i.imgsafe.org/7e35784.jpg).

Comment: Second image shows that there must be an issue with xml file. please check xml file.